# Firebase error message if directory doesn't exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show error message with toast if firebase database doesn't exist.

an example: The app will not be able to connect to the firebase database when when I delete the database, delete the firebase project or if there is no database.

So the app should display an error toast message "databese doesn't exist" or "not connection to databese" when all this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't mention in your question if you are looking for Firebase Real-time database or Cloud Firestore, I'll give you an answer for both. So in case of Firebase Real-time Database, there is a special location at `/.info/connected` which is updated every time the Firebase Real-time Database client's connection state changes. Here is an example from the official documentation:

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (connected) {
                System.out.println("connected");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not connected");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
        }
});
```

This is how you can know if the client is connected to the server or not.

In case of Cloud Firestore, when you are offline and you are using a `get()` call, the result will be from the cached copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using.

To check if the data is from cache or from Firestore servers, you can use the following line of code:

```
String source = querySnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache() ? "Local Cache" : "Firebase Server";
```

Comment: Hi Alex, this code works great for me, exactly as I want. Thank you.

Comment: nice share @AlexMamo :)

Comment: @GastónSaillén Thanks Gastón! It's good to have you around here ;)

Answer (score 1):

Reference your main node of your database and use exists() to check if that reference exists or not

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(!dataSnapshot.exists())
        Log.e("No database","Connection Lost");
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

if not exists there will be nothing to check in that database

Comment: Hi, this code works well for checking database but not work if I delete my project from firebase.

Comment: if you delete your project from database, your google-services.json will not work since it wont receive any sort of connection with that project, there is no way to know programatically if a database project is deleted , you can know if there is no data at that desired database

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. the other answer works well. Thank you again.